# Jquery add and remove class to a div placed inside a li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass, removeclass

i wanna add and remove class to a div placed inside a li, and when i click another li ineed to remove 
rightshapeactive class from the activated div

```
<ul id="servicesleft">
    <li class="left1">              
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        <div id="rightshape" class="t"></div>
    </li>   

    <li class="left1">              
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        <div id="rightshape" class="t"></div>
    </li>   

    <li class="left1">              
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        <div id="rightshape" class="t"></div>
    </li>
</ul>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#servicesleft').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
        $(this).find('#rightshape').addClass('rightshapeactive').siblings().removeClass('rightshapeactive');
    });
});
```

Comment: id attribute value should be unique in all the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. After `.find('#rightshape')`, the selection is referring to the `div`, and not the `li`. `.end` returns you to the previous selection.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#servicesleft').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
    $(this).find('#rightshape')
      .addClass('rightshapeactive')
      .end()
      .siblings()
      .find('#rightshape')
      .removeClass('rightshapeactive');
  });
});
```

This might be even better:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#servicesleft').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
    $('.rightshapeactive').removeClass('rightshapeactive');
    $('#rightshape', this).addClass('rightshapeactive');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the class "t" instead: http://jsfiddle.net/m27ra/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#servicesleft').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.t').removeClass('rightshapeactive');
        $(this).find('.t').addClass('rightshapeactive');
    });
});
```